# what does a.push() adds value to in an array?

Tags: javascript, arrays

My question is if in javascript, I make an array `a = [2, 3, 4, 5]` and type  `a[5] = 10` and then `a.push(5)` then does the compiler adds 5 to end of an array or to the first undefined spot?

I found out that it adds to the end of array , that is `a[6] == 5` . but then my question is how does compiler finds if an array has ended ? of course it cannot decide that an array has ended if it identifies an unidentified value because then array would have ended after value 5 . So,how does it know that array has ended?

Answer (score 6):

The summary from MDN for [`Array.prototype.push()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/push):

> The `push()` method adds one or more elements **to the end of an array** and returns the new length of the array.

It knows where the end is because the `length` of the array is always [numerically greater than the highest index in the array](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/length).

```js
var a = [1, 2, 3];

a[49] = 4;

document.write(a.join(" - "));
document.write("<br>");
document.write("Array length: " + a.length);
document.write("<br>");

a.push(5);

document.write("<br>");
document.write(a.join(" - "));
document.write("<br>");
document.write("Array length: " + a.length);
```

Answer (score 2):

The push operation pushes values starting at `a[a.length]`, which results in the array growing by *N* items (1 in the described example).

The length is determined by the largest used index, so in your example `[5]` if the largest index and 6 is the length.